Count consecutive excel cells where value is greater than 50 from left side only using excel formula

I am trying to count consecutive excel cells in a row where value is greater than 50 only from left side using excel formula.
For e.g - in 3rd row, there are consecutive 3 cells having values >50. However, counting from left, there are 2 cells with values >50 and then a value < 50. Hence, o/p will be 2 and not 3.
Expected output is in 'count' column.

It should be >=50 because if its only >50 then the second one should be 1 and not 3, you will not fix that or clarify the same

@MayukhBhattacharya Before the edit to show additional columns, the values were being shown at 2 decimal places rather than rounded to nearest digit.  The second value in the second row was 50.04 — so I presume that it still is, it's just not displaying properly.  Which is why, OP, it's best to put data in a Table, not an Image. (Plus, users can copy/paste it for testing)

@Chronocidal noted! You're right. Values are still in 2 decimal places.

=FIND("0", CONCAT(--(B1:E1>50))&"0")-1

This just changes the cell values into 1 (>50) and 0 (≤50), joins them all together into a string, slaps another 0 on the end (to cover off the edge-case whereby all the values are >50), and then finds how many 1s there are before the first 0.  This ensures that it only counts from the left-edge.



Count
26-Oct-2024
25-Oct-2024
24-Oct-2024
23-Oct-2024




1
52.38
40.3
50.39
46.32


3
52.94
50.04
50.82
47.53


2
53.06
51.39
35
65


3
53.48
50.68
50.69
47.64


1
53.48
47.64
50.68
50.69


0
47.64
53.48
50.68
50.69




With older functions an array formula and drag down:
=COLUMN(INDEX($A1:$D1,0,MATCH(0, IF($A1:$D1>50,1,0),0 )))-1
or simpler
=MATCH(0, IF($A1:$D1>50,1,0),0 )-1
The first value is in column A. If not corrigate the subtracted value according to the first data column numbered value.
If it is possible that all the values are greater then 50 use this advanced formula:
=IFERROR(MATCH(0, IF($A1:$D1>50,1,0),0 )-1,COLUMNS($A1:$D1))

This formula also throws error if the entire range is greater than 50. Else gives correct o/p.

Pls. see edited formula.

Edit: The last formula using FREQUENCY() won't work, updated with a better version and refer the last example


=XMATCH(0,HSTACK(SCAN(0,B2:G2>=50,LAMBDA(x,y,y*(x+1))),0))-1



this formula gives the highest count of consecutive cells having value >50. For e.g - in 1st row, o/p should be 1. But if there are 2 more values which are >50 in let's say 22-Oct and 21-Oct, your formula will give o/p as 2.

@user3471438 perfect i was assuming that only edited now.

ok ... this is working. But randomly. Like 50% cases are giving #N/A o/p. Any idea?

@user3471438 how would i know what you have, i cant simply assume, while you were editing i had already proposed my solution. and shouldn't it be >=50 where as your post describes about only >50 since both are different.

Found the reason. If the entire range is >50, then it is giving error. Else it is counting ok.


Formula in A2:
=LEN(TEXTSPLIT(BYROW(N(B2:G5<50),CONCAT),1))

Or:
=FIND(1,BYROW(N(B2:G5<50),CONCAT)&1)-1


You could use BYROW and SCAN:
=BYROW(SCAN(0,A1:D4,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b>50,a+1,a*0))),LAMBDA(y,MAX(y)))



this is also giving o/p as highest count of consecutive cell values >50. required o/p is consecutive count only from left side.

Same logic as @Black Cat, just find the first entry less than 50:
=BYROW(B2:G7,LAMBDA(r,XMATCH(TRUE,HSTACK(r,0)<50)-1))



BTW you can get Frequency to work, it would be one way of doing it with older versions of Excel. Normally the result is in the first element of the frequency array, but when all cells in a row are greater than or equal to 50, the total count is in the second element of the array. You could do something like this:
=INDEX(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:G2>=50,COLUMN(B2:G2)),IF(B2:G2<50,COLUMN(B2:G2))),1+AND(B2:G2>=50))


Just for fun: =BYROW(B2:G5,LAMBDA(r,XMATCH("^[1-4]?\d$",r,3))).

I had no idea that you could use pattern matching in xmatch...OK, pretty recent to be fair

=BYROW(B2:G5,LAMBDA(r, XMATCH(TRUE,r<50)-1))


